# Can hybrid Vulcan/Humans procreate, or are they like mules?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, hybrid

Like full blooded Vulcans, the hybrid Spock is driven by the urges brought on by pon farr. Can hybrid Vulcan/Humans reproduce, or are they like horse/donkey hybrids on Earth, physically willing, but biologicaly unable to create offspring?

Comment: If one of them is Jolene Blalock, I'd be willing to try. For science.

Comment: As a side note, female mules can give birth to offspring, but it is rare. There has, however, been no known cases of a male mule siring an offspring.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the Star Trek novel "Yesterday's Son", Spock discovers that he fathered a son with Zarabeth when he was stranded in the past in the 'All our yesterdays' episode. So a male hybrid produced by a Vulcan male / Human female can be fertile with humans.

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Son

Comment: Zarabeth was humanoid, but not human. She was Sarpeidonian.

Comment: Human or not, this does tell us that Spock was fertile

Answer (score 21):

No limitations have been mentioned for hybrids. There are some canon cases of hybrids having offspring:

In [The Drumhead](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Drumhead_%28episode%29), crewman [Simon Tarses](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Simon_Tarses) is put on trial and suspected of having falsified his origins as 1/4 Vulcan, when he is in fact 1/4 Romulan (to which he pleads the <strike>fifth</strike> seventh). Since we know that Romulans are an offshoot species of Vulcans, odds are that their genetics are relatively similar for reproduction.

Crewman [Daniels](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Daniels_%28Crewman%29) was also of multiple origins, one of which was Vulcan, suggesting that interbreeding is quite extended by the 31st century.

In the non-canon part, a few lines were dropped from Star Trek IV where it would have been revealed that on the Genesis planet (in III), [Saavik](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Saavik) had had sex with Spock (since he was going through a few instances of *pon farr* thanks to the accelerated aging), and later took a maternity leave.

Comment: Hopefully it was the Kirstie Alley Saavik.

Comment: Actually, Simon Tarses is direct evidence that human/vulcan hybrids can have offspring. Not because he is 1/4 Romulan and that Romulans are closely related to Vulcans. But because he *claimed* he was 1/4 Vulcan, *and everyone he interacted with in the Federation, including doctors, believed him.*

Comment: @iMerchant Kristie Alley was in Star Trek II, not in III. But yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Kirk's son with a Romulan/Klingon in the book universe was sterile.  They hint that one biology is dominant. Spock is never called a human and B'elanna is always called a Klingon or hybrid.

So, unlike a mule, which is a blend, Star Trek humanoid hybrids seem to be more like a phenotype than true hybrids.

Comment: Which book had Kirk having a son with a Romulan or Klingon?

Comment: There *are* Star Trek books? I thought there were only Tv shoes an movies...

Answer (score 0):

In the Star Trek novel "[Yesterday's Son](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday's_Son)", it's revealed that Spock and [Zarabeth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Zarabeth) (seen in the TOS episode [All Our Yesterdays](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Our_Yesterdays_(episode))) had a child named Zar.

From the blurb:

> "The starship Enterprise must protect the Guardian – or destroy it.
>   But Spock has already used the portal to journey to the past. On the
>   planet Sarpeidon, 5,000 years ago, Spock knew a beautiful, primitive
>   woman. **Now he has gone back to meet his son!**"

The cover even sports a picture of the boy in question:

[image]